# How to sort a multidimensional class in php with different subarray name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Can someone help me about my problem... I have a php multidimensional array and i need to sort it by "PRICE" with PHP... I tried to use sort() but it don't work because every main array have a different currency name..

Here is an example of my array :

```
array(3) {
  ["MLN"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["EUR"]=>
    array(23) {
      ["FROMSYMBOL"]=>
      string(3) "MLN"
      ["TOSYMBOL"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(0.01699)
    }
  }
  ["BTC"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["EUR"]=>
    array(23) {
      ["FROMSYMBOL"]=>
      string(3) "BTC"
      ["TOSYMBOL"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["PRICE"]=>
      int(8769)
    }
  }
  ["LTC"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["EUR"]=>
    array(23) {
      ["FROMSYMBOL"]=>
      string(3) "LTC"
      ["TOSYMBOL"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(141.47)
    }
  }
}
```

Is someone who have an idea to sort my currencies by PRICE?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The easiest and most strait forward way is make an new array with prices only and then sort that array with php built in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$sorted = [] ;
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    $price = reset($item)['PRICE'] ;
    $sorted[$price] = [$key => $item] ;
}
krsort($sorted);
$array = [];
foreach ($sorted as $sort) {
    $keys = array_keys($sort) ; 
    $array[reset($keys)] = reset($sort) ;
}
unset($sorted);
print_r($array);
```

Will keep keys and sort array.

Output :

```
Array
(
    [BTC] => Array
        (
            [EUR] => Array
                (
                    [FROMSYMBOL] => BTC
                    [TOSYMBOL] => EUR
                    [PRICE] => 8769
                )

        )

    [LTC] => Array
        (
            [EUR] => Array
                (
                    [FROMSYMBOL] => LTC
                    [TOSYMBOL] => EUR
                    [PRICE] => 141.47
                )

        )

    [MLN] => Array
        (
            [EUR] => Array
                (
                    [FROMSYMBOL] => MLN
                    [TOSYMBOL] => EUR
                    [PRICE] => 0.01699
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your fast reply... You have solve my probem !!! :)

Comment: While this works, it creates unneeded overhead, since it creates not only one new array, it creates two new arrays, which may cause memory/performance issues if your base array is very huge.

Comment: You're right. It create one new array (`$sorted`). Final `$array` is overrided.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['EUR']['PRICE'] - $b['EUR']['PRICE']; 
});
```

I'm using an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in this example but you could also define the comparison function separately.

Comment: This. Simple and effective. But shouldnt it be either < or > instead of the minus?

Comment: Works and simple, but removes the keys "BTC", "LTC", "MLN".

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt the comparison function must return an integer. However, using `>` would probably work too because the boolean return will be cast to an integer internally.

Comment: @Syscall You're right, my fault. I updated my answer from `usort()` to `uasort()`.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt & Simon it could be `<=>` which also works for strings arrays and objects, and is like a standard way to compare. It makes it really clear. But in case of numeric comparisons it's just the same of `-` or `<`, `>`.

Comment: @sidyll true (as of PHP 7)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a somewhat messy object oriented approach, I've made a class that is supposed to order an array of classes based on a shared property:

https://gist.github.com/kyrrr/b208693a59f184fe607660e0dfa8631d

A class that represents your data (quick and dirty):

```
class Exchange{
    public $currencyName;
    public $toSymbol;
    public $rate;
    function __construct($name, $to, $rate)
    {
        $this->currencyName = $name;
        $this->toSymbol = $to;
        $this->rate = $rate;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
  $orderer = new PropertyOrderHelper();
  $foo = new Exchange("MLN", "EUR", 0.0169);
  $bar = new Exchange("BTC", "EUR", 20);
  $exchanges = [$foo, $bar];
  var_dump($orderer->orderBy($exchanges, "rate"));
  var_dump($orderer->orderBy($exchanges, "rate", 'desc'));
```